# How to implement several image buttons on a single, highlighted line

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am making a user interface where I want each line to respond with a color effect when rolled over, coloring the entire background of that particular line in a given color. In addition, each line should contain several small symbols (buttons) that also should respond to user clicks and rollovers.

The only way I know to do this using the anchor tag, but once I have used that, I cannot nest another anchor within it. Is there a way to produce "nested buttons" or a workaround (preferrably not including javascript) to accomplish my goal here?

maralbjo

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file could contain:

```
li:hover {
   background-color: #3f3; /* whatever color you want */
   list-style: none;
}
```

Your HTML file could then just have a list of items:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="alink.html"><img src="image.png" alt="mybutton"></a></li>
 <li>Line</li>
 <li>Goes</li>
 <li>Here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only thing is on top of that you have to add a script in javascript to assign the .hover class to the li element on hover. Why? Because IE does not recognize :hover pseudo-class on anything but anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make it work in older IE browsers without scripting. :(

I ended up doing what Dmitri Farkov proposed in his comment: adding hover behavior via script. There is an interesting alternative I used for a while, though: [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Maybe it will suit you better.

Comment: Thanks. How do we define "older IE browsers" in this context? I have no trouble sacrificing IE6 and older.

Comment: James' code should work in IE starting from IE7: [CSS 2.1 selectors compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)